# Помогите найти компонент

Tags: customview, android

Всем отличного настроения!

В моем приложении необходимо использовать такой компонент:
[image]
[image]

Аналог в действии можно увидеть в приложении QBank.

SlidingDrawer - не подошел, так как нижний макет скрыт до нажатии кнопки.
SlideUp Panel от tokudu не подошла, так как макет2 весь реагирует на касания, тем самым закрывается. И плюс, тень под макетом1 должна быть, а в SlideUp Panel сверху.

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть готовые решения такого компонента? или придется переписывать один из выше указанных

Comment: мне кажется быстрее написать самому, анимация + тач листенер

Comment: Можно не всё самому написать, а взять гугловский NavigationDrawer и переписать.